# Google Voice not automatically notifying new text message

Tags: notifications, google-voice, sms, android

My Google voice app on my EVO is not telling me when I have a text message even though I have notifications turned on. I have to open Google voiced hit refresh to get new items.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a mobile app, not a web application.

Answer (score 1):

I would verify under Sync and Notifications settings in Google Voice that Background data is enabled along with Synchronize Inbox.  Besides those settings, I can't think of anything else that would prevent Google Voice from receiving the new SMS messages.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I was able to fix that on my droid was to sign out of google voice:

Menu > Settings > Sign out

Then sign back in and select 'synchronize inbox' during the sign in wizard.

Answer (score 1):

In the app settings, go to "Sync and notifications"

Under the Notifications heading, there's an option for "Receive text messages" 
Select "Via the Google Voice app"

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

What I found to be a good fix is to check your settings and under *Sync and data* make sure text messages are being received to the Google Voice app instead of messaging.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that clearing "all data/cache" and signing back in and now it works again.  Weird.

Answer (score -1):

I uninstalled my google voice app and reinstalled it now its working. I have a google pixel 4a